# Why does yo not recognize private yeoman generator?

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have a private yeoman generator on my gitlab.

After using `npm install -g [url_to_my_generator]`, I found that yo can't recognize it.

But when I clone it to local and then use `npm install && npm link`, it works fine and appears in "Available Generators".

Here is my generator's package.json

```
{
  "name": "generator-my-generator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "xxx",
  "keywords": [
    "yeoman-generator",
    "generator"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "email": "xxx",
    "url": "xxx"
  },
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://xxx/generator-my-generator.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "yeoman-generator": "^0.19.0",
    "chalk": "^1.0.0",
    "yosay": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "files": [
    "app"
  ]
}
```

And my environments:

```
OS: Windows 7
yo: 1.4.7
npm: 2.13.5
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: `yo` has a [problem](https://github.com/yeoman/environment/blob/master/lib/resolver.js#L124) with npm global path. Try `yo doctor` to see if everything is working as it should.

Comment: Thank you @YanFoto. I made a mistake. As I put the app folder into generators folder, the `files` property in package.json should be `["generators"]` (`["generators/app"]` also works).

Answer (score 0):

Two troubleshooting techniques:

1. Run `yo doctor`. That's your best friend for any issue with Yeoman.
2. Make sure the [`files` property of your `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) includes your generators.